# TypeError: this.loaderWidget is undefined on showing loader

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am getting

> TypeError: this.loaderWidget is undefined

while doing

```
$.mobile.loading('show');
```

I have correctly included all the js and css files directly from the CDN. I am able to see the loader while changing the pages, but when I try to do it manually using

```
$.mobile.loading('show');
```

it is giving error.

I am using jQuery Mobile v1.3.2

Comment: Are you loading jquery-ui? If yes, remove it.

Comment: No, I am not loading jquery-ui.

Comment: When are you calling the loader?